# Angular ng-click changes all array elements

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I got a array of objects in my scope.
Additionally I got a button that I would like to equip with a ng-click routine, that changes a certain attribute of every object in the array.

Can I do that all in a one-liner in ng-click? Alternative, I can also equip my scope with a function and pass on the array, that I would like to adjust all elements in.

Example:

Scope:

```
{"languages": [
    {
      "hide": false,
      "title": "Deutsch",
      "level": 7
    },
    {
      "hide": false,
      "title": "Englisch",
      "level": 6
    },
    {
      "hide": false,
      "title": "Französisch",
      "level": 2
    }]
}
```

And my respective button (with a pseudo function at the moment):

```
<a class="button" href="#" ng-click="angular.forEach($scope.languages, function (item, index) {item.hide=true});">Alle ausblenden</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that in a function of the scope. Keep your view as simple as possible. Put JS code in the controller so that you can unit test it, document it, format it.

And you don't even need to pass the array, since it's in the scope:

```
ng-click="hideAllLanguages()"
```

Isn't that much more readable?

Comment: Looks straightforward. However, the language element in scope is one. I'd like to re-use the logic also for other arrays within the scope. How can I pass a reference to the function, so that I can reference it? E.g. locations, languages, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you want to use the same function with several arrays, then pass the array as argument to the function.

Comment: You are completely right. I got it: ng-click="hideChildElements(languages)" and the corresponding function would be: $scope.hideChildElements = function(parent) { angular.forEach(parent, function (item, index) {item.hide = true}); }